# Flutter/Firebase - Create future function for gathering firebase images

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display some images downloaded from firestore but when I load this screen it takes a while to download the images. To make this a bit more seamless I am thinking of creating a Future function that will allow me to download the images first, and then display them all at once. I have created a future function to get the data from Firebase but I now need to create a new function to download the images. Here are my two future functions:

```
     Future getCardData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('cards')
    .where('Event', isEqualTo: widget.documentid).getDocuments();
  }

  Future getCardImage(int index) async {
    final _data = getCardData();
    return await FirebaseImage(_data.data.documents[index].data['img_url'], maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024);
  }
```

And then I would implement like so:

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: getCardData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot)  {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: const Text('Loading...'));
      }
      return GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder:
        // ignore: missing_return
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
          print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['img_url']);
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
              child: Center(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    child: getCardImage(index);
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

But i'm just not sure the best way to create the future function to download the images because when I run the above, i get the following error:

```
The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You need is not really clear. Where are you struggling exactly with your future ?

Comment: When I run the above, i get the following error: The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>', i will adjust my question to try and make the need more clear thanks

Comment: What is the line that is triggering this error ? Looks like you have to convert the data to another format before rendering it

Comment: I assume here: child: getCardImage(index); as this returns a Future rather than an ImageProvider is flagging the error

Comment: I thought so too but it's weird that it is asking for an `ImageProvider<dynamic>`. It should be expecting a `Widget` there... Does it work if you replace it with `Text('test')` ?

Comment: Yes that works fine, how strange

Comment: What is for sure is that `getCardImage()` should not be async. You need to do the async job elsewhere, save the content in the state then return it synchronously when asked in the `build()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Would this get you there?

```
     Future<FirebaseImage> getCardImage(int index) async {
final _data = getCardData();
return await FirebaseImage(_data.data.documents[index].data['img_url'], maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024);
```

}